# jQuery autocomplete id increment

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I'm trying to customise the following Auto Suggest jQuery plugin:
[Ajax autocomplete with AJAX](http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/#styling)

What I'm having trouble with is the autocomplete div which id is generated randomly using the following method:

```
uid = Math.floor(Math.random() * 0x100000).toString(16);
```

This way even few instances of the plugin are wrapped with divs having unique ids but these ids obviously change every time sript is called. What I'm trying to achieve is to be able to generate the unique id for each instance but same each time so I can reference to it using CSS. I tried for loop but with no luck.

Any help appreciated.

The whole plugin code can be found here:
[plugin code](https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete/blob/master/src/jquery.autocomplete.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the class name instead?

alternatively use jquery to access divs with names beginning with Autocomplete:

```
$("div[id^=Autocomplete]").css
```

Or

```
var acs = $("div[id^=Autocomplete]");
acs.eq(0).css...
acs.eq(1).css...
```

Comment: Well that sound like an idea but I have two instances of an auto suggest and each needs slightly different css styling. Maybe defining i=0 at the beginning of the script and having div id='autocomplete' + ++i will do?

Comment: That was my other idea but was not sure what you needed. But that would of course work too. See update for another way